# Unable to display GUI application from Windows container

Tags: docker

I have an image with a GUI application, with base image of microsoft/windowsservercore. Application is installed correctly in the image, however I'm unable to display it on host machine. Have read several articles on this on Google and they suggest to install XServer for Windows and then we can display the application on host machine. I have been trying to run following command (as suggested in most of the articles), however it does nothing and I don't get the display. Please assist.

```
docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 eft
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DISPLAY` would be useful for Linux container.

As [mentioned here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-a-gui-application-on-docker/48437/12):

> WindwosServerCore image does not come with binaries for UI applications so I doubt this will ever work in servercore image but Microsoft insiders can use new bigger WindwosServer image which I beleive have those libraries intact.

This [thread adds](https://forums.docker.com/t/gui-app-in-windows-container/59063):

> I understand that you can run GUI apps but the rendered elements are not shown on any desktop. Lars Iwer [MSFT] writes in the discussion below the article:
>
> > In the container image as it is right now, GUI elements will be rendered in session 0. UI automation should work with that (e.g. programmatically searching for a window etc.).
>
> Session 0 is the session in which all system services are run and is by definition non-interactive. Sessions, Stations and Desktops are means of isolation in Windows (NT) and whether an application can show a UI and receive user  interaction depends on whether it has an access to a Station with a Desktop.
> Processes in Session 0 do not have that by default.
> However it used to be possible to “Allow services to interact with Desktop” and it is also possible to run interactive services in other sessions than Session 0 (pay attention to “as it is right now”). Therefore, it would be interesting to hear some expert insights from Microsoft/Docker team on that…